# Unable to debug ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis-7.5

I am getting below error and unable to debug my ASP.NET project.

"Unable to start debugging on the web server"

I am using .NET Framework 4.0 with Windows 7 Operating System (IIS 7.5.7600). It debugs successfully 'some times'! However, suddenly starts giving error when I run it again after few code changes here and there. Below are the things which I have already tried out to fix this:

1. Re-registered ASP.NET by command aspnet_regiis -i successfully
2. Confirmed that ASP.NET State Service is running
3. IIS folder pointing to correct path
4. Debug mode is true in web.config

However, this does not work always. Sometimes, when I either restart my computer or Visual Studio, re-register the ASP.NET, then it starts debugging again. And then starts giving error after few runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved by cleaning the solution! So whenever it gives debug error, I clean the solution in Solution Explorer.